# Get dot file of ROS graph w/o rqt_graph

Tags: ros, graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a headless rpi3 for ROS development with an IMU shield. Its not ideal but works for the purpose.

When building new nodes and connecting them would like to see the ros graph. I've looked at rqt_graph which is great but don't want to install all the X deps on the pi and really not prefer to forward X either.

I see that the now deprecated rxgraph does have a `--dot=DOTFILE` argument, but rqt_graph does not. Is there any other way to export the graph as an image or dot file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243865/get-dot-file-of-ros-graph-w/o-rqt_graph/) by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-09-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is distributed by nature. Is there anything preventing you from using another non-headless machine, configuring it to use your RPi as `ROS_MASTER_URI` and running `rqt_graph` on there?

---

Edit: If you don't have a working DNS for all the involved hosts, don't forget to set the `ROS_IP` env variable to the IPs of those hosts (so on `my_rpi3` with ip `10.10.4.2`, set `ROS_IP` to `10.10.4.2`), *not* to the IP of the master. That is what `ROS_MASTER_URI` is for.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) on 2016-09-16**:
I'm slowly realizing how distributed ROS is (its a good thing imo). I knew nodes could connect remotely but completely forgot about `ROS_MASTER_URI`. I'll give that a shot!

**Comment by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) on 2016-09-20**:
@gvdhoorn that worked!